# Google sheet formula for getting the same value in respective cell when the cell duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

if the same value is duplicated in the particular column, i need the the same text to be pasted respective to the above cell in the same column.

Eg,

Column A1 has 1111 and column B1 has abcd , if 1111 duplicated in A2, abcd should be auto posted in B2.

Is is possible in conditional formatting???

Comment: Is there any other formula to do the above conditions????

Comment: No Sorting is not allowed.

Comment: The column A may contain anything, but when it is duplicated the column B should be filled with the respective value to Column A.

Comment: Can anyone give me the answer

Comment: @Naveen Krishnan I gave it a try below.  I think that's what you were looking for but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that does what I think you want.

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sht=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('ColumnADuplicates');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var cell = e.range;
  var row =  cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  var value = cell.getValue();
  //Logger.log('row = ' + String(row) + ' , column = ' + String(col) + ' , value = ' + String(value));
  var nextCell = sht.getRange(row, col+1);
  if(col==1)
  {
    for(var i=0;i<rngA.length;i++)
    {
      if(rngA[i][0] == value   && i+1 != row)
      {
        nextCell.setValue((rngA[i][1] !='undefined')?rngA[i][1]:'');
        break;
      }
    }
   }
}
```

Here's what my sheet looks like:

[image]